# Create a new column by evaluating an expression in another

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following example, variable `expr` contains an expression in the form of a string. However, the last `mutate` command does not evaluate that expression correctly. Could you help me understand why?

```
symbols <- expand.grid(data.frame(matrix(rep(c("+","-",""),8),ncol=8)))

df <- symbols %>%
  transmute(expr=paste0(1,X1,2,X2,3,X3,4,X4,5,X5,6,X6,7,X7,8,X8,9)) %>%
  mutate(eval=eval(parse(text=expr)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `rowwise()`

```
df <- symbols %>%
         transmute(expr=paste0(1,X1,2,X2,3,X3,4,X4,5,X5,6,X6,7,X7,8,X8,9)) %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(v1=eval(parse(text=expr)))
```